# Vuetify template in Vuejs/Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've confused about vue-ionic. I've decided to make mobile app with Ionic. That's okey. Then I couldn't use Angular. I installed vuejs for frontend. (vue-ionic).After that I decide to use Vuetify for material design. Now which template should I use ?  or Vuetify template tags ? When I use vuetify tags, would it cause problems on the mobile device?

Answer (score -1):

I have been creating a website and vuetify has a section on there website where it tells how to adapt your website to the size of the device using tags like:
xs sm or md and you can also make some things only apear on small devices 
i recomend you take a look at this serie from academind that shows a litle of what you can do with vuetify:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXY1UyQfSFw&list=PL55RiY5tL51qxUbODJG9cgrsVd7ZHbPrt&index=1